# Facebook App Invite Setup for Unity Game

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-graph-api

I want to send app invite, so as per current Facebook SDK version its supported or not because I found deprecation related message on their website.

[FB.Mobile.AppInvite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.Mobile.AppInvite)

[Sending App Invites](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/archive/docs/app-invites/overview/)

If its deprecated and removed soon from Facebook SDK, then what is alternative way for sending App Invite?

For Facebook App Invite, I want to setup my custom UI layout rather than Facebook default UI, is this possible?

Sketch for my designed layout is here:

[image]

App Invite related code, I found from here so that Facebook dialog box can loaded.

[Facebook Unity SDK Tutorial - Share, Invite, Get Friends, ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVuVwTwKjxE&t=654s)

Comment: There probably isn’t any alternative. And no, you can not create such a custom target selector any more, all ways to do that have been removed as well.

Comment: Basically if App Invite removed from Facebook SDK then what is alternative for me to use ??